# CSS navigation bar hover not activating

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover, nav

I have been trying to make this seriously simple hover for my portfolio website but after testing with every single existing option I do not seem capable of managing to work.

I have read lots of threads about this issue but none seemed to give a proper solution which worked.

Please find below an image of the code I have for my nav bar:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZS0Y.png)

It is really not hard but the hover is stubborn.
I have traded and modified everything and I am now out of hopes.

Can any of you be so kind and see what could be the cause for this?

PS: It is not the final hover form since I was simply testing.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fix the issue!
It was as simple as it looked, basically had a z-index bigger than the nav div and when I changed this it started working.

Thank you all for your time I hope this somehow helps anyone else who's troubled.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the class `animated` & `zoomIn` from it. These class are from `animate.css` so it might create an issue.